# Python imports

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Используя конструкцию вида:

```
from a import *
```

Но не используя все классы/функции и т.п. из `a`, можно ли сказать, что это влияет на скорость работы программы, на количество требующейся памяти? Или для python это не страшно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя конструкцию `from smth import *`, если у вас там действительно очень много объектов и суб-объектов, повлияет на время выполнения - интерпретатор будет бегать по файлам выискивая все "зависимости" и создавая ссылки на объекты.
Для того, чтобы точно определить список импортируемых объектов и не допустить "каскадного импорта до упора", существует директива `__all__`

Comment: Это будет выполнено только раз? Или это может как-то повлиять и вдальнейшем при выполнении программного кода?

Comment: Только 1 раз за все время выполнения программы.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то время выполнения будет примерно одно и тоже, за исключением того, что используя конструкцию from smth import * в локальном контексте будут созданы ссылки на все объекты определенные в smth. "Каскадный импорт до упора" в любом случае произойдет.

Comment: Верно, что что происходит привязывание имён (типа `x=1`). Но привязывание имён ничего не импортирует, никакого "каскадного импорта нет". См. [Неявный импорт в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569357/23044)