# Неявный импорт в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу разобраться в системе импортов.
Почему когда я делаю:

```
import os.path
```

то мне доступен `os.walk`, который находится в `os`, хотя я явно не импортирую `os`? Почему-то со своими *package* такой финт не прокатывает. За счет чего это происходит?

upd

Я понимаю, что импорт вносит импортируемое в пространство имен модуля. 
поэтому определив модуль 'myutils.py' c

```
import requests
```

в другом модуле получается следущая картина

```
import myutils
resp=myutils.requests.get('http://ya.ru') # работает
resp2=requests.get('http://ya.ru') #  NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Есть какая то особенность в механизме import os в os.path? Я понимаю, что os.path есть часть os, а не 2 абсолютно отдельных package, но хочу точно понять механизм.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Overlapping Python import statements - bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16866679/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303179/why-does-importing-a-python-module-not-import-nested-modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Импорт в Питоне объединяет две операции](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

1. найти (загрузить  и проинициализировать) модуль
2. ввести новые имена в текущем окружении  (как операция присваивания `=`)

На [этапе поиска (пункт №1)—из спецификации `import`-конструкции](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching):

> This name will be used in various phases of the import search, and it
>   may be the dotted path to a submodule, e.g. `foo.bar.baz`. In this case,
>   Python first tries to import `foo`, then `foo.bar`, and finally
>   `foo.bar.baz`. If any of the intermediate imports fail, an `ImportError`
>   is raised.

то есть `import a.b.c` импортирует модули `a`, `a.b`, `a.b.c` и более вложенный модуль не может быть импортирован успешно, если импорт неудачен для любого модуля выше.

На [этапе присвоения имён (пункт №2)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> If the module being imported is not a top level module, then the name
>   of the top level package that contains the module is bound in the
>   local namespace as a reference to the top level package. The imported
>   module must be accessed using its full qualified name rather than
>   directly

`import a.b.c` в Питоне делает доступным `a` имя в текущем пространстве имён (например, в глобальном пространстве имён модуля, который импортирует `a.b.c`) и присваивает атрибут: `a.b` и атрибут атрибута: `a.b.c` соответствующим загруженным модулям (аналог: `a = sys.modules['a']`; `a.b = sys.modules['a.b']`; ..).

Хотя вопрос с подводхом, потому что `os` не является Питон-пакетом ([`__path__` атрибут не установлен](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__path__)) и `os.path` является обычным атрибутом (таким же как `os.walk`) с той разницей, что `os.path` является модулем и `os.py` содержит хак: `sys.modules['os.path'] = path` (что разрешает `import os.path` конструкцию). `import os` сам по себе уже делает `os.path` доступным без `import os.path`.

---

Перефразируя вопрос, используя более регулярный пример:

> Почему когда я делаю: <strike>`import os.path`</strike>`import html.parser`
>   то мне доступен <strike>os.walk</strike> `html.escape`, который находится в <strike>os</strike>`html`, хотя я явно не импортирую <strike>os</strike> `html`?

`import html.parser` импортирует как [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) так и (естественно) `html.parser` модули и так как `html/__init__.py` (выполняемый на этапе импорта `html`) определяет `escape` функцию, то `html.escape()` также доступна как если бы мы просто выполнили `import html`.

> Почему-то со своими package такой финт не прокатывает. За счет чего это происходит?

Если `module.name` после `import module` не работает, то это значит что ваш `module/__init__.py` не определяет `name`.

В сторону: работоспособность `module.name` не зависит от `__all__`. `__all__` документирует какие имена являются публичными (формально имена доступные по `from module import *`), чтобы не добавлять к каждому имени, которое не является частью интерфейса, `_` в начале (имена типа `_name` по умолчанию исключены из `from module import *`). Но это не запрещает явное обращение такое как `module._name` (этого следует избегать, но если очень хочется, то можно). В сторону: не используйте `from module import *` вне REPL или вне `__init__.py` файла (пример оправданного использования: [`asyncio/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f9c682b2b3d6b2a87d60da51d857fdb4a1db89f5/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py)—`asyncio` предоставляет "плоский" публичный интерфейс (имена доступны прямо как `asyncio.name`), не смотря на то что реализация распределена по многочисленным вложенным модулям).

Comment: я окончательно запутался. По вашим словам import os.path устанавливает os в текущем пространстве имен ( по правилу "делает доступным 'a' имя") и таким образом мы видим os, откуда дотягиваемся до path, который часть os. Но я попробовал обычные package и import a.b не делает доступным a.c (то есть как "а" не устанавливается в пространство имен). Может потому что это пакет и там атрибуты ищет в __init__.py. Я пошел вписал туда __all__=['c'] и это тоже не помогло.

Comment: @vitidev не "по моим словам", а согласно официальной документации (см. явную цитату в ответе—если не понимаете, попросите, я переведу дословно) и фактическому поведению всех известных реализаций Питона. Если у вас что-то не работает, то спрашивайте именно об этом (`os.path` это не общее правило (os не пакет)—плохой пример). Для ясности: если у вас есть *пакет* `a` и в нём есть модули `.b1`, `.b2`, то `import a.b1` не обязан делать доступным `a.b2`. `import a.b1` создаёт в текущем пространстве имён `a` (как будто вы выполнили `import a`—поэтому и другие атрибуты могут быть доступны помимо a.b1)

Comment: цитату я понимаю, просто она больно туманная для человека пришедшего с других языков. Она говорит примерно "модуль верхнего уровня вставляется в локальное пространство имен и становится доступным через имяссылку", а оказалось что код этого верхнего модуля выполняется при этом (и выполненный даже условно где то внутри import a.b2 делает его доступным), а __all__ работает только для from..import * и при import a не является описателем доступных атрибутов.

Comment: @vitidev я не понял что вы написали (забудьте слово "ссылка" особенно если вы его в С++, Java выучили—хотя "имя" в Питоне можно реализовать в С в терминах указателя, но само понятие гораздо проще), но согласен язык у цитаты слишком сухой (он точный, что хорошо для reference документации, но для первого знакомства можно менее формальный язык использовать, поэтому я не стал буквально переводить, а просто привёл пример с a.b.c). Похоже проблема что вам надо забыть некоторые понятия, которые к Питону не имеют отношения (ситуация проще, если к вас нет проблем с обычным присваиванием: `a = mod`)...

Comment: ... Обновите ваш вопрос (или новый  задайте, если проблема не относится к тому что `import a.b` делает `a` имя доступным) приведите конкретный пример ожидаемого поведения и что вместо этого у вас получается.

Comment: У меня не было проблемы импортов. Я хотел понять механизм и вы мне его пояснили. Я не понял ответ сразу потому что трактовал bound как просто "подключение пространства имен доступное через имя (без выполнения внутреннего кода, которое на самом деле выполнялось)"+мое неверное понимание ___all___. Руководствуясь вашими словами я попробовал разные варианты и в мою голову пришла ясность, что куда и откуда берется, то есть я понял. Но вопрос и  ответ не требуют обновления. они полностью соответствуют друг другу.

Comment: @vitidev ясно ли что загрузка модуля (и сопутствующее выполнение кода на верхнем уровне) НЕ имеет отношения к присваиванию имён? (в ответе явно как два отдельных пункта указано) Например, `importlib.import_module('a.b.c')` выполняет первый пункт полностью (находит/загружает модуль), но (в отличии от `import` конструкции) НЕ выполняет второй пункт: ни одно имя в локальное пространство имён не добавляется. Это мне нравится в Питоне, что,  как правило, статически в исходном коде явно имена определены (без зловредных хаков, `import a.b.c` ровно одно имя добавляет "a").

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45819/discussion-between-vitidev-and-jfs).

Answer (score 0):

Импортировать `mypackage.mymodule_XXX` и использовать `mypackage.mymodule_YYY` вы сможете только в том случае, если в файле `__init__.py` вашего пакета вы явно импортируете `mymodule_YYY`.

Допустим у вас есть пакет `mypackage`:

```
`/mypackage/`
    __init__.py
    mymodule_XXX.py
    mymodule_YYY.py
```

`__init__.py:`

```
from . import mymodule_XXX
from . import mymodule_YYY
```

Тогда вы cможете в вашей программе сделать так, как хочется:

```
import mypackage.mymodule_XXX

# здесь можно смело использовать mypackage.mymodule_YYY
print(mypackage.mymodule_YYY)
```

Что касается `myutils`. Импортируя модуль, вы просто вводите в пространство имен вашей программы переменную `myutils`, переменную `requests` вы не вводите, поэтому логично, что она не определена. Переменная же `myutils`, которая является модулем и имеет свое пространство имен, имеет переменную `requests`, поэтому через `myutils.requests` вы можете получить к ней доступ.

Comment: То что по `import mypackage.mymodule_XXX` вы рекомендуете сделать неявно доступным `mypackage.mymodule_YYY` — не является хорошей идеей. Более ожидаемые варианты когда каждый модуль отдельно  импортируется (например, `import http.client`, `import http.server`) или когда вложенные модули являются деталью реализации, а публичная функциональность доступна на уровне самого пакета: `import asyncio`. Стоит заметить, то что `http.server` импортирует `http.client` внутри, следует рассматривать как деталь реализации (если вы используете оба модуля в своём коде, то импортируйте оба явно).

Comment: То, что вы видите рекомендации там, где их в принципе нет, не является нормальным. Более ожидаемым является вариант, когда сначала ответ читается, потом анализируется и только потом, при необходимости, комментируется.

Answer (score -1):

```
print(len(globals()), globals().keys())
import os.path
print(len(globals()), globals().keys())
```

когда вы импортируете os.path, на самом деле происходит импорт os, потом видимо у os просто запрашивается атрибут path, те импорт уже не происходит

```
8 dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__cached__', '__spec__', '__builtins__', '__loader__', '__file__'])
9 dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__cached__', '__spec__', 'os', '__builtins__', '__loader__', '__file__'])
```

правильно будет from os import path

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то кроме описываемой в книгах системы package (папка с __init__.py) + вложенные модули, есть и другая система адресации, когда модуль вписывает у себя в __all__ другой модуль (а может и без __all__, я вижу внутри os.py "import ntpath as path") и при таком импорте исполняется этот модуль (как бы сам по себе являясь заменой __init__.py)